# How to pull the data from mainframe files to hadoop HDFS using flume

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera, flume, cloudera-cdh

I'm using cloudera CDH5 ,and there is a requirement to pull data from mainframe files to hadoop hdfs using flume .
Could some one help me what are the steps need to take care ..

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need Flume? Sqoop 1.4.5 now has a mainframe connector that may be a better out-of-the-box fit.